# Proving that a pointset is $\Sigma^0_2$ iff it is a countable union of closed sets.

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

I'm (independently) going through  Moschovakis' text on DST, and I'm trying to solve problem 1B.4, which asks the reader to prove that for any pointset, $P$, $P\in \Sigma_2^0$ if and only if $P = \bigcup_{i=0}^\infty F_i$  where all $F_i$ are closed. For the forward direction, I've managed to demonstrate that $P$ is a projection over $\omega$ of the intersection of closed sets, but I'm unsure of how I would finish this directionof the proof. Am I approaching this the right way, if so what steps do I take next? Otherwise, how should I approach this problem?

Comment: In the case of the natural numbers, at least, the set $\{y\mid\exists x\varphi(x,y)\}$ is a countable union of the sets $F_i=\{y\mid\varphi(i,y)\}$.

Comment: How does your text define $\Sigma^0_2$ sets? As countable unions of $\Pi^0_1$ sets ? If so, you're done, right?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, no Moschovakis defines $P \in \Sigma_2^0$ as being $P = \exists^\omega \neg Q$ where $Q\in\Sigma_1^0$.

Comment: But then $Q$ is open, being $\Sigma^0_1$ so $\lnot Q$ is closed and the $\exists^\infty$ is a countable union of sorts? This notation he uses is unfamiliar to me; I don't have this book myself..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $\exists^{\omega}$ is a projection from $\mathcal{X}\times \omega$ to $\mathcal{X}$, where $\omega$ is the natural numbers endowed with the discrete topology.

Comment: So it does come down to a countable union, really. So you’re done.

Comment: I mean that if $A \subseteq \mathcal X \times \omega$, then $y \in \pi[A]$ iff $\exists n \in \omega: y \in A \cap (\mathcal X \times \{n\})$; so calling $A \cap (\mathcal X \times \{n\})$ $A_n$ and note that $A$ is closed implies all $A_n$ are too (also true for open) and so $y \in \pi[A] \iff y \in \bigcup_n A_n$, so we get a countable union.